# Show specific category posts on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show only specific post categories on the "Blog" page, which you can view here: http://dev.n8geeks.com/blog

Having tried literally everyone version of code which apparently helps with this, it leaves me with totally different styling or missing parts, such as no date or excerpt.

At the moment, it's showing all categories (naturally) - how do I show a specific category whilst the formatting stays true to the current look? I simply want it to look exactly as you see there, except only showing a specific posts category.

My second issue is that my "Videos" page is using the code below to show only posts from this specific category, however it's using the same template parts (content_single for example) as the "blog" page, which would be fine, but I've edited the content_single page files in order for it to look how i want (i.e. to display a thumbnail with a fancy box around it, but i don't want this on the Videos posts).

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=videos&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
  $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />

  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So, I basically want to display ONLY the videos posts category on the videos page, but without the box that you see when you click on the post name (as seen here: http://dev.n8geeks.com/how-to-recognize-early-signs-of-autism/) - hence why i want to use different template parts.

Comment: First, welcome to SO, the question and answer site for you programming problems. Now, to your problems. You've scoured... The entire PLANET?!? You've absurdly overstated your two problems and the likelihood of finding pre-built answers, neither of which gives me the impression they are unique or unanswerable. I know for sure, though, I'm not click a bit.ly link obscuring it's final destination.

Comment: I obscured the final destination because i don't want the UR to be indexed in Google - nothing malicious here Jared, thanks for the warm welcome by the way! And yes, i've scoured the entire planet, not even God has the answer to this question.

Comment: If it's really that obscure and even the big hombre in the ether can't puzzle his way through it, then it may not belong here. Just state your question with enough detail to understand it. You may get an answer, some answers, an answer or two that help. But the absurdity of the claims it contains now are noise to most of us. Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and consider this question may be considered as **Too localized**, which is one of the options when voting to close a question. Does that describe you question in a nutshell?

Comment: Okay, maybe i'm overestimating a little, but i said that for emphasis, to say that this is a rather complex issue for someone not in the know such as myself. It should definitely be an easy answer for someone in the know, let's hope so, at least.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the default loop on the blog page add the following under the  `get_header();`.

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&category_name=videos' );
```

If you don't have a template defined, copy `index.php` and rename it `home.php` then follow the directions above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, now i know how to reference a different copy of "content.php", which is what i wanted. Only issue now, is i cannot figure out for the life of me how to show the posts from the videos category on the pag. I know you added the code above, however when added to index.php (duplicated and re-named of course) it only shows the videos page without the posts.

Comment: I changed the index.php in order to display only the "blog" category posts on the blog page, this worked like a charm. Just cannot get it to work for the "videos" page, with it using a different version of content.php and content_single.php (i.e. without thumbnails and additional divs - and only displaying "videos" posts).

Edit: Okay, i can make it use a different content.php, without the thumbnails and additional div's, however the posts are no longer displaying.

Comment: @NikkiMather For the videos page rewrite the default loop. Overwrite the loop by adding `query_posts( 'category_name=videos' );` under the `get_header();`. Remember to accept the answer by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Brian. If i change the default loop as you suggest, this also changes the "blog" page, too, which isn't what i want. I'm trying to basically remove the box you see on this page; http://dev.n8geeks.com/how-to-recognize-early-signs-of-autism/ - the bit above "posted on".

This is a post from the "videos" page, the same box appears on the "blog" page as it is meant to, but i don't want the box to appear on posts made under "videos". Does that make sense? So what i'm trying to do, is make "blog" and "videos" use different iterations of content.php and content-single.php.